# Windows has detected that your fan is not running properly

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling

I was receiving the message that my CPU fan was not working properly. And, in fact it was not. Replaced fan, old fan 4 wire adjustable speed fan in an HP laptop. Purchased a 4 wire adjustable speed fan for the particular laptop that I have. Replaced fan. Fan works great, and quiet as a mouse. Love it. PROBLEM: Error message still appears when starting or restarting laptop. How do I get rid of the error message. Not the fan, as stated fan works great. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try removing the CMOS battery or take note of your current settings and perform a Reset.  I don’t believe your hardware is smart enough to tell the difference between two fans.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Fan is not an HP Fan  ( Purchased a 4 wire adjustable speed fan for the particular laptop that I have ) it may be tricky to remove the message.

Best approach:  Contact the manufacturer  of the Fan and ask them how to remove the HP message.

If the Fan manufacturer cannot help with the message, ask for a refund (or write it off) and get an HP Fan.

There is not much else you can do.